# SpriteKit iPad view scaling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I can't find anything about this when searching around so I decided to ask.

For some reason when I try to create a GameScene and try to scale it to the iPad according the suggestions around here. I get black borders around my view like so:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
 import SpriteKit

 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

   var scene: GameScene!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false;

    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    print(scene.frame.size)
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }

  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
      return .Landscape
    } else {
      return .AllButUpsideDown
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }

  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

and this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let testLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello World!")
    testLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    testLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addChild(testLabel)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

  }

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of the black borders around my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set in your project targets in the deployment info section Devices to universal (I think you set it up with iPhone) see screenshot:

[image]

Then set `scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill` to `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill` and after that run your app and see the result with no black borders:

[image]